# number of php query results does not match terminal results from Oracle's Toad

Tags: php, oracle10g

I got the fix but I need the explanation why and leaving this as a references for other people:

The Problem is we got this view, say A, that is built upon another view B. If you do a select * from view A, you get say 37 records. Great, now if you run this via PHP adobdb, it gives you 525 records!

The reason why this happened as it turns out, thanks to my coworkers, is because view B have this funky line that PHP ignores but TOAD doesn't:

```
          AND p.created_on > TO_DATE ('23-SEP-10')
```

The fix was:

```
          AND p.created_on > TO_DATE ('2010/09/23', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Summary:
If your php query results does not match your terminal results then try this solution.

Comment: Add it as an answer and solve it yourself. Makes it easier for people to see what the answer is, as most will just glaze over the question text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was this line:

```
      AND p.created_on > TO_DATE ('23-SEP-10')
```

The fix is:

```
      AND p.created_on > TO_DATE ('2010/09/23', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```